# Angularjs attribute with html content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes, directive

I want to have html content in my attribute to style the output, with lists and strong words etc.

```js
angular.module('calc.popover', [])
  .directive('popover', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/partials/popover.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            content: '@'
          
          }
      
      }
  
  };
```

```html
 <popover title="I am a popover" content="Many Text <br> New line. <ul><li> a list </li></ul>"></popover>
```

How can i do this? If i do this, the output shows me the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'ngTransclude' property to get html template content in directive,
and pass content to directive like this:
`<popover title="I am a popover"><br> New line. <ul><li> a list </li></ul>"></popover>`
 For working Example check: http://plnkr.co/edit/5RKBZRBmEH6PMvmbZomt?p=preview